# Error on loading new media on mediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have been stuck with this problem for quite a while now. In the mediaPlayer i've created everything runs smooth in the initial playing stage but when the user selects the next or previous option, the application gives me a `(0,-107) error` along with the `attempt to call getDuration without a valid mediaplayer`

**The code:**

```
      public void playPodCast(int index) {
        try {
            urlToSend = toGet.get(index).get("URL").toString();

            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(urlToSend);
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            onPlayerLoad();
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);

            mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

here the `onPlayerLoad()` is just a method to hide all the views while the mediaPlayer is loading.

```
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    onPlayerLoaded();
    updateProgressBar();
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

the `onPlayerLoaded()` loads back on the view.

```
public void updateProgressBar() {
    seekHandler.postDelayed(updateSeekTime, 100);
}

private Runnable updateSeekTime = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        long totalDuration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
        long currentDuration = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

        // Displaying the total time duration
        seekRight.setText("" + utils.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));
        // Displaying completed playing time
        seekLeft.setText("" + utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));

        // Updating the SeekBar progress
        int progress = (int) (utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration,
                totalDuration));
        seekBar.setProgress(progress);

        seekHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
};

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

// @Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    seekHandler.removeCallbacks(updateSeekTime);
}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    seekHandler.removeCallbacks(updateSeekTime);
    int totalDuration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
    int currentPosition = utils.progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(),
            totalDuration);

    // forward or backward to certain seconds
    mediaPlayer.seekTo(currentPosition);

    // update timer progress again
    updateProgressBar();
}
```

Here, `private Handler seekHandler = new Handler();`

Like I said before, the initial call to `playPodCast(index)` does not give me any errors, it works very smoothly. But when the user clicks on the next and previous buttons, the error is generated. The next and previous methods do not give out any errors if implemented without the `updateProgressBar()`, everything runs unbuggyly. So why am I getting this error ? I have no clue why ... please do help.

Here's the implementation of the next button:

```
btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (getPosition == totalList - 1) {
            getPosition = 0;
            playPodCast(getPosition);
        } else {
            getPosition = getPosition + 1;
            playPodCast(getPosition);
        }
                    }
});
```

where `getPosition` is the position of the media file being referenced.

And I also did try

```
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mediaPlayer.start();
    onPlayerLoaded();
    updateProgressBar();
}
```

**Update 1:**

I found that the error occurs when using the `prepareAsync()`, the program works fine on `prepare()` but is super laggy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `getDuration` is getting called by your `updateSeekTask` while the new media is preparing. This will error. What's the duration of an unprepared video?

The solution is to cancel any callbacks of the `updateSeekTask` when the user clicks next, and reinstate them once the media is ready.

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    if (getPosition == totalList - 1) {
        getPosition = 0;
        seekHandler.removeCallbacks(updateSeekTime); // Cancel me! 
        playPodCast(getPosition);
    } else {
        getPosition = getPosition + 1;
        seekHandler.removeCallbacks(updateSeekTime); // Cancel me!
        playPodCast(getPosition);
    }
}
```

Then in `onPrepared` restart the task as you do currently:

```
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mediaPlayer.start();
    onPlayerLoaded();
    updateProgressBar();
}
```

You should still use `prepareAsync`. If you just use `prepare` everything will wait until the media is prepared. This is the lag you experience. It will fix your problem (since even the task will wait) but it's not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the following:

```
int totalDuration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
```

inside the `Runnable updateSeekTime()` make the `totalDuration` a global variable and refer initialize the value of the totalDuration inside the `onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)` like this:

```
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    onPlayerLoaded();
    totalDuration = mp.getDuration() // mp is the MediaPlayer instantiated by this method
    updateProgressBar();
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

and Presto you are done ... Hope this helps someone.